# Python threading.Event reset?

Tags: python, multithreading, events

I have a function that I want to run repeatedly on `threading.Event`s. However it looks like you can only use each `Event` instance a single time.

Is there a way to reset the `thread.Event` so that it can be triggered again? I imagine it could look something like this:

```
import threading
import time


def waiting_function(trigger):
    while True:
        trigger.wait()
        # do stuff after trigger
        trigger.reset()

trigger = threading.Event()

waiting_thread = threading.Thread(target=waiting_function, args=[trigger])
waiting_thread.start()

time.sleep(3.)  # do some stuff that takes a while
trigger.set()
time.sleep(3.)  # do some stuff that takes a while
if not trigger.is_set:
    trigger.set()
```

Alternatively, do I have to create a new `trigger` after each set and share it between the threads?

Comment: I think you just need to remove `trigger.reset()` (which should be `trigger.clear()` by the way).

Comment: Oh! I just didn't read the docs thoroughly enough. `trigger.clear()` is definitely what I was looking for. Works great when I replace reset with clear.